# how to deal with duplicate record field with lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, monoids

given this piece of code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

module Foo where

import Control.Lens ((^.), makeFieldsNoPrefix)
import Prelude hiding (id)

data Bar
  = Bar1 { _id :: Int
         , _name :: String
         }
  | Bar2 { _name :: String }

$(makeFieldsNoPrefix ''Bar)


data Foo = Foo { _id :: Int
               , _name :: String
               }

$(makeFieldsNoPrefix ''Foo)

a = (undefined :: Foo) ^. name -- compiles fine

b = (undefined :: Foo) ^. id -- doesnt compile
{-
    • No instance for (Monoid Int) arising from a use of ‘id’
    • In the second argument of ‘(^.)’, namely ‘id’
      In the expression: (undefined :: Foo) ^. id
      In an equation for ‘b’: b = (undefined :: Foo) ^. id
-}
```

As far as I can understand, it seems `id` needs an instance of Monoid because of Bar that could fail when the instance is of type `Bar2` (which doesnt have an `id` field).

But since I'm working on a Foo (which always has an `id` field) it should work, doesnt it ?

I know I could solve this with prefixing the field with the class name like:

```
data Foo = Foo { _fooId :: Int, _fooName :: String }
```

but if there is a nice solution without cluttering my fields name then I'm all for it :-)

Comment: Uff, there are at least three things here that I'd consider generally a bad idea: **1.** making record fields for sum types. (Lenses do to some degree solve the problems that come with that, but as you've encountered  this brings its own problems.) **2.** Duplicate record fields. (Always were a half-baked concept; only `OverloadedLabels` has made sense of this.) **3.** Don't re-use standard names for something different, in particular not for something as fundamental as `id`.

Comment: Yeah, I know about 1 and 2 but I thought lens would solve their issue :-(

Comment: Is it sure that **1** is a bad idea when used with lens ? It seems strange to me that the first example on http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens.html is using sum types of records if it was a bad practice

Comment: Well, **I** consider it a bad idea. Opinions may vary.

Comment: You can get around a lot of these issues with [generic-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens).  And as a bonus, no  TH splices!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the issue here is caused in part by the record used in a sum-type. We can generate a lens for `name` for Foo since each constructor has a `name` field; but only one constructor has an `id`. This causes TemplateHaskell to generate the following `HasId` class, which you can see for yourself by running `:browse Foo` in ghci:

```
class HasId s a | s -> a where
  id :: Traversal' s a
```

As you can see, it set the type to `Traversal'`. Since there can only be one `HasId` typeclass, when you `makeFields` on `Foo` it'll re-use the same typeclass, and even though it CAN generate a lens, the typeclass method `id` only has type `Traversal`, and you need a `Monoid` to use `^.` on a traversal.

If you swap the ordering of your `makeFields` calls in the module you'll notice the typeclass is now generated with `id` as a `Lens`; but now the second `makeLenses` call fails to compile because it's generating a `Traversal`, not a lens.

To sum up the problem, you're expecting the typeclass's `id` method to change types based on how it's used (by picking either a Lens or Traversal), but that's not how typeclasses work in Haskell.

You have a few options here, but you really need to decide on what you want the semantics to be. The safest is to stick with what you've got here, (use the Traversal) and always use `preview` a.k.a. `(^?)` to access the id field. Alternatively you could generate separate combinators; a `fooId` and a `barId`, one a lens and the other a Traversal. Alternatively you could implement the `HasId` typeclass manually, and provide a 'default' id for when it's missing (or call error), but both of these would result in an unlawful lens.

You could do something really gross and determine whether each type's `id` field is a Lens or Traversal using Type families or something like that; but it's going to be unidiomatic and really hard to understand. It's more work than it's worth.

The crux of it is, you **can't** have a valid lens for `id` if there's a constructor fo the type that doesn't have an id. It's up to you how you want to handle that case.

Comment: Such a well detailed response, this is great. Thank you so much !!
I chose to use the lens lib because I thought it'd solved the haskell record issue but I guess the easiest solution is still to prefix my record with the class name :-(

Comment: No problem :) If you're interested in learning more about lenses I'm releasing a comprehensive lenses book later this month! https://leanpub.com/optics-by-example/